# Проблема с занесением информации в базу данных

Tags: html, php

Возникла проблема добавления информация в базу данных, не пойму, в чем проблема.

```
<form action="file2.php" method="post" name="form1"> 
    <label>Имя: <br />
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    </label>
    <label><br />
        Фамилия:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" />
    </label> 
    <label><br />
        Отчество:<br /> 
        <input type="text" name="otchestvo" id="otchestvo" /><br />
    </label> 
    <label>
    </label>
    <p>
        <label>
            <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Занести сотрудника в базу"/>
        </label>
    </p>
</form>
```

Код обработчика file2.php:

```
<?php
include('bd.php');
if (isset($_POST['$name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['$name'];
}
if (isset($_POST['$lastname'])) {
    $lastname = $_POST['$lastname'];
}
if (isset($_POST['$otchestvo'])) {
    $otchestvo = $_POST['$otchestvo'];
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
if (isset($name) && isset($lastname) && isset($otchestvo)) {
    /* Здесь пишем что можно заносить инфу в базу */
    $result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO sotrudniki (name, lastname, otchestvo) VALUES ("$name", "$lastname", "$otchestvo")');
} else {
    echo "<p>Вы ввели не все данные</p>";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment:     <pre><code>Ваш код</code></pre>  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`$result = mysql_query('INSERT INTO sotrudniki (name, lastname, otchestvo) VALUES ("$name", "$lastname", "$otchestvo")');`** - вы используете не те кавычки. $param заменяется только внутри двойных кавычек, а у вас они, фактически, одинарные. Поменяйте местами кавычки либо используйте конкатенацию строк: **`, "'.$otchestvo.'")'`** .